# Systemd service using 100% of my CPU when start as service and it doesn't if I start it without systemd

Tags: c#, mono, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Ubuntu with the latest updates. I made a systemd service to run a script (Server.exe) (Mono, C#) when my server starts. Here's its configuration:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=My
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    PIDFile=/home/my/server/bshserver.pid
    WorkingDirectory=/home/my/server
    ExecStart=/home/my/server/start
    User=my
    Group=my
    SyslogIdentifier=My-Server
    StandardOutput=syslog
    Restart=on-failure
    KillSignal=SIGINT

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

"start" file:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo Starting MyServer in /home/my/server
    /home/my/server/Server.exe
    exit $?
```

I was to try another Ubuntu, fail too

When I run the script /home/my/server/start normally (simply /home/my/server/start on my terminal), it is working as expected. Top reports it's using between 2 and, say, 5% of my CPU, which is normal. 
But when I start it with service start, htop says it's always using at least 100% of my CPU (one core)

What could explain such a big difference in CPU usage?

Comment: What does this have to do with c#?

Comment: Server.exe is written C# (mono)

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368037/103793 maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues I'm seeing:

- In order to start a `mono` application it must be run with the command `mono`. Use `which mono` to find the full path of `mono` installed on your server. As it is your script will report a failure every time its run.
- Your systemd configuration has `OnRestart=on-failure` set, which is working more effectively than intended. Since your script will always fail `systemd` will continuously try to restart the service.

Update your script to include calling `mono`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Starting MyServer in /home/my/server
/user/bin/mono /home/my/server/Server.exe
exit $?
```

If your service uses `ServiceBase` then use:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Starting MyServer in /home/my/server
/user/bin/mono-service /home/my/server/Server.exe
exit $?
```

- Your script may imply that `Server.exe` will fork. Add `Type=forking` to your configuration.

```
    [Unit]
    Description=My
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    Type=forking
    PIDFile=/home/my/server/bshserver.pid
    WorkingDirectory=/home/my/server
    ExecStart=/home/my/server/start
    User=my
    Group=my
    SyslogIdentifier=My-Server
    StandardOutput=syslog
    Restart=on-failure
    KillSignal=SIGINT

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. I read somewhere that maybe related to the console output.

Comment: @Serjaru yeah here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368037/103793